# Change pieSliceText value in Google Pie Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I have the following:

```
function getArrayOfItems(value, id, title) {
 ...
};

var theData = [
        getArrayOfItems(data.average.toFixed(2), 'average', 'Average'),
        getArrayOfItems(data.smallest.toFixed(2), 'smallest', 'Smallest'),
        getArrayOfItems(data.largest.toFixed(2), 'largest', 'Largest')
    ];
```

The value is eventually passed to the chart object options as such:

```
var options = {
   amount: value,
   id: id,
   title: title,
   pieSliceText: 'value'
};
```

And then the value is applied to the pie chart.

I have the pie chart showing, for eg, 3506.00, but what I want the value to show is $35.06. At what point can I apply something like

```
getArrayOfItems('$' + (data.average/100).toFixed(2), 'average', 'Average'),
```

The above causes the chart to not render. But I know I need something like this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `push()`

try this

```
 var theData = [];
 theData.push(getArrayOfItems(data.average.toFixed(2), 'average', 'Average'));
  .....
```

but you have to push each an every element to an array. Better loop on `data` variable and call getArrayOfItems one time.